# Am I allowed to freely use content included in the D&D SRD?

Tags: copyright

Are there any restrictions on using content included under the [D&D System Reference Document](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf)?

As a hypothetical, if I were writing a fantasy book, could I freely throw in a Yrthak or Gray Render with no restrictions?

I'm thinking of publishing a supplement for another RPG under their Open Game License that includes creatures in the D&D SRD, which has all relevant information in its first pages.

Comment: For those who know about law but not about D&D SRDs or other TLAs, could you explain what this is, and anything you know about it that might be relevant to your question?

Comment: http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf                             All of the relevant information is in the first two pages of this. I'm thinking of publishing a supplement for an another RPG under their OGL that includes creatures included under the D&D SRD, and I want to make sure that's okay.

Comment: Edit this into your question; comments aren't permanent.  And the more you can do to make your question self-contained, without requiring people to read a bunch of external stuff, the better chance you have of someone being willing to take the time to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

**No you cannot**

The 4th paragraph identifies proper names (among other things) as “Product Identity” and subject to the restrictions in Clause 7 of the license which starts with:

> 7. Use of Product Identity: You agree not to Use any Product Identity, including as an indication as to compatibility, except as expressly licensed in another, independent Agreement with the owner of each element of that Product Identity.

Notwithstanding, Wizards of the Coast have only licensed what is *in* the SRD. If it is in some other book or on their website but not in the SRD, normal unlicensed copyright applies.

Comment: The items identified as "product identity" are stated to not be Open Game Content though: "The following items are designated Product Identity, 
as defined in Section 1(e) of the Open Game License 
Version 1.0a, and are subject to the conditions set 
forth in Section 7 of the OGL, and are not Open 
Content:"

Comment: @GeoMax I agree but what’s your point?